# Input text field and button width change dynamic

Tags: html, css

I want to let my text field's width can change dynamic when resize the screen, at mean time I have

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    #nameinput {width:auto;}                 
}
@media (min-width:1025px){
    #nameinput{  width:300pt;}                   
}
<div   style="left: 20px; width:805pt" >
     <label for="inputname"><b><%=bt%></b></label>
    <input id="nameinput" name="nameinput" style="font-size:10pt; text-transform: uppercase; ">
</div>
```

1. But the input box did is suddenly become small is not progressively according the screen size
   **( change max-width: to some bigger number then can see the text field progressively change)**
2. When the screen small enough cause the label and the input field separate to two line , the text field become very big again

Comment: give width in %, so it will change dynamic

Comment: Use relative units like % as @HirenPatel suggested or em. Absolute units like px or pt are rigid -- do you plan on printing this form with a printer? pt units are best if you plan on using a printer, but it's the worst for displaying on screens (actually in probably the worst).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using the following css can avoid the problems that I mention above

```
#nameinput{
                max-width: 300pt;
                width: 80%;
                min-width: 60pt;
               }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give `100% width` of your container on smaller screens and specified `300pt` on your larger screens .

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    #nameinput {width:100%;}
}
@media (min-width:1025px){
    #nameinput{  width:300pt;}             
}
```

Comment: the text field still looks like change either not change or reduce to half .

Comment: Have you added this meta tag  
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">

Comment: I had                                                                                                       
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, maximum-scale=1" />